# Shared calendar. How to constraint user to only create private events

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I'm creating an app where users can take appointments with pro.
I want a full sync between the app and the users calendars.
So I created a shared calendar (because I only need to watch for one calendar and not 1/user) that will containt every users events.
So I added read/write access to every users. Events created from my backend are fully private. But how to constraint the user to only create private event in their google calendar app for my shared calendar?

Comment: If you are an administrator, restricting users to only creating private events doesn't appear to be a standard feature in the Google Calendar API or the Google Workspace Admin Console. Unfortunately, I have not come across any existing Google developer documentation that addresses this matter. Perhaps you could consider submitting a feature request on the [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).